# formvalidation.io - it validates only the first time, after submit allows empty field to be submitted

Tags: javascript

The first validation works correctly (if the input is empty it requires me to enter a value and the submit button becomes disabled until I enter some data).
After submit, form clears, and if I click the submit button with input being empty, it doesn't warn me anymore to enter some data. The form is submitted and I have 401 error.

```
$('.deviceStatus, .accountsLogin, .sendMessage').formValidation({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            excluded: ':disabled',

        });

        $('.sendMessage').on('success.form.fv', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var $form = $(e.target);
            var fv = $form.data('formValidation');
            fv.defaultSubmit();
            // reset form data
            fv.resetForm(true);
            $form[0].reset();
        });

        $('.sendMessage').ajaxForm({
            resetForm:true,
            beforeSubmit: function () {
                if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to send this message?')) {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            success: function () {
                toastr.success("Message sent", "Success");
            },
            error: function (response) {
                toastr.error(response, "Error");
            }
        });
```

```
public function sendMessage()
{
    $post = $this->input->post(null, true);

    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request() && !empty($post)) {
        try {
            $this->sendingMessage($post);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->output->set_status_header('401') //is ok that i have 401 error if i submit unvalid data (empty field in this case), but I want to not be allowed in the first place to submit an empty field.
                ->set_output($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}

/**
     * Reset the form
     *
     * @param {Boolean} [resetValue] If true, the method resets field value to empty or remove checked/selected attribute (for radio/checkbox)
     * @returns {FormValidation.Base}
     */
    resetForm: function(resetValue) {
        for (var field in this.options.fields) {
            this.resetField(field, resetValue);
        }

        this.$invalidFields = $([]);
        this.$submitButton  = null;

        // Enable submit buttons
        this.disableSubmitButtons(false);

        this.$form.trigger($.Event(this.options.events.formReset), {
            fv: this,
            resetValue: resetValue
        });

        return this;
    }, //this is resetting my form, but it doesn't add validation back, unless I first enter a value and delete it
```

I found in documentation that defaultSubmit() is submitting the form without doing validation, but if I remove it no submitting is done.

Also, if I remove fv.resetForm(true);
$form[0].reset();  and I let the ajax form to deal with resetting the form, after submit the button is disabled and that helps because is enabled only if i enter a value in my textarea. But if submit again, the button is not disabled. I don't understand how it works.

Does anyone have any idea about what can I try at least? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, IMO i think it would be better to adapt to [Constraint Validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Constraint_validation)

Comment: I understand...but unfortunately I must solve it with this library, for example I am used working with https://jqueryvalidation.org/, I find more confusing formvalidation.io.